# Batch convert WebP files to GIF files offline?

Tags: batch, conversion, gif, image-conversion, webp

Writing a batch script to convert all WebP files to be GIF format.

Looking at [the closest utility offered by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/dwebp), I don't see an immediately obvious way to do that. I don't like having to use online converters for individual files, one by one, I'd rather do it offline using my computer in batch.

Comment: Did you check https://imagemagick.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) is cross-platform command line utility that can batch convert images from one format to another. You can download the latest versions [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Once installed, ensure that ImageMagick is available from the command line (ex. on Windows, add `C:\path\to\ImageMagick` to your Path). Then run:

```
magick mogrify -format gif *.webp
```

in the same folder as your `.webp` files (this can also be done from ex. a `.bat` file).

---

*Note that you may need to use just `mogrify -format gif *.webp` without `magick` depending on the options you selected during the ImageMagick installation, your platform or if you are using an older version of ImageMagick.*

---

Answer (score 2):

Using this method (`mogrify`), random files gave me significant dropouts, in my results.  Per the suggestions in this thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977561/how-can-i-avoid-dropouts-when-using-imagemagick-mogrify-to-convert-webp-file ), I got much better results, using `convert`.